# How to maintain a previous variable

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

Im having an issue where im setting up an PHP pagination table, which is grabbed from mysql. Everything is working fine although the issue im running into is when i'm attempting to browse through the data.

Basically i want the data filtered for the relevant item, which i get from a post value from a previous page.

Although when i click my links to move onto the next dataset its blank because my post data has been replaced by the pagination and my WHERE statement fails. If i just do a general select everything the process works fine. If i hardcode the id it works fine as well, but this needs to be dynamic.

Sooo my question is- is there anyway to maintain the original post state or possibly save the value?

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Code:

```
   <?php

$id= $_GET['search'];

  require ("db.php");


    $tbl_name="LOG";        //your table name
    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE host_id_fk='$id';";
    $total_items = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "search3.php";    //your file name  (the name of this file)
  $limit = 10;                 //how many items to show per page
  if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;      //first item to display on this page
  } else {
    $page = 0;
    $start = 0;               //if no page var is given, set start to 0
  }


    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "Select *,
(
CASE
WHEN (LOG.status = 1) THEN
'UP'
WHEN (LOG.status = 0 ) THEN
'DOWN'
ELSE
'State Unknown'
END
) AS `outcome` from Ping.LOG where host_id_fk='$id' LIMIT $start, $limit ;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($page == 0) $page = 1;          //if no page var is given, default to 1.
  $prev = $page - 1;              //previous page is page - 1
  $next = $page + 1;              //next page is page + 1
  $lastpage = ceil($total_items[0]/$limit);    //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
  $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;            //last page minus 1

  /* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
  */
  $pagination = "";
  if($lastpage > 1)
  { 
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination pagination-centered\"><ul>";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
      $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">previous</a></li>";
    else
      $pagination.= "<li class=\"disabled\"><a href=\"#\">previous</a></li>"; 

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2)) //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    { 
      for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
      {
        if ($counter == $page)
          $pagination.= "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#\">$counter</a></li>";
        else
          $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a></li>";         
      }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))  //enough pages to hide some
    {
      //close to beginning; only hide later pages
      if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))    
      {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
        {
          if ($counter == $page)
            $pagination.= "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#\">$counter</a></li>";
          else
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";         
        }
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"#\">...</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";   
      }
      //in middle; hide some front and some back
      elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
      {
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"#\">...</a>";
        for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
        {
          if ($counter == $page)
            $pagination.= "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#\">$counter</a></li>";
          else
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";         
        }
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"#\">...</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";   
      }
      //close to end; only hide early pages
      else
      {
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"#\">...</a>";
        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
          if ($counter == $page)
            $pagination.= "<li class=\"active\"><a href=\"#\">$counter</a></li>";
          else
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";         
        }
      }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
      $pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next</a></li>";
    else
      $pagination.= "<li class=\"disabled\"><a href=\"#\">next</a></li>";
    $pagination.= "</ul></div>\n";   
  }
?>
```

Comment: Add it your `id=$id` to all your pagination links.

Comment: Not sure if you're open to using jQuery, but I love this plugin: http://tablesorter.com/docs/, it keeps my sorting intact when using the pager add-on: http://tablesorter.com/addons/pager/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it your search=$id to all your pagination links. For example

```
$pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev&search=$id\">previous</a></li>";
```

Another option would be to store it in a session variable:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['search']) && is_numeric($_GET['search'])) {
    $id= intval($_GET['search']);
    $_SESSION['search'] = $id;
} else {
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks.. i though i might have to do this, but i was't sure if it was that simple.

Comment: ....but please fix the XSS vulnerability here!!!!! ( $id = htmlentities($_GET['id']); )

Comment: @symcbean good recommendation, now checking if get variable is numeric and forcing it to be an int.

Answer (score 1):

You could save the `$_GET` value to the session, thus keeping it across page loads

```
<?php
session_start();
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['search'])) $_SESSION['search'] = '';
$_SESSION['search'] = (isset($_GET['search'])) ? $_GET['search'] : $_SESSION['search'];
...
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE host_id_fk='{$_SESSION['search']}';"
...
$sql = "Select *,
(
CASE
WHEN (LOG.status = 1) THEN
'UP'
WHEN (LOG.status = 0 ) THEN
'DOWN'
ELSE
'State Unknown'
END
) AS `outcome` from Ping.LOG where host_id_fk='{$_SESSION['search']}' LIMIT $start, $limit ;";
```

Obviously you would want to make sure it's the correct type of data using the above method!

Or as an alternative, append `$_GET['search']` to you pagination links, thus keeping it across page loads.

I'll just give one example here because there are many lines of code:

```
$pagination.= "<li><a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter&search={$_GET['search']}\">$counter</a></li>";
```

Comment: Yours was correct as well. But the Pitchinnate's change was a bit easier. Thanks!

Comment: @mmSQL No problem :) I like to offer alternative solutions where I can